# Play mp4 video and mp3 audio in firefox using html5 audio video tag?

Tags: asp.net, html

I am using html5 audio video tag to play audio and video in asp page, I have got audio and video data in the form of data uri from server using ajax call and passing thid data uri to src of audio and video tag but its not working in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your audio format is not supported. Have a look at this page. For firefox you might need to add an *ogg* file. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp